# (Apache) pages only load when adding index.php?p=

Tags: apache

It looks like Apache (or Craft?) isn't routing all of the requests to index.php. So http://SITENAME/index.php?p=admin/install works, but http://SITENAME/admin/install doesn't. The issue is this is happening with every URL, so the HTML for the install page loads, but none of the assets (CSS, JS) do.

Here's my issue in picture form:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Disabling the `omitScriptNameInUrls` config option makes it work. Not sure if this is a "solution" though

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to enable the .htaccess file in the root directory of your site.

By default, the .htaccess file included with Craft is named htaccess (without the period). The period needs to be added to the beginning of the file.

Comment: .htaccess was enabled. I verified this via adding an invalid string to the .htaccess file, which caused index.php to give a 500 error (if I recall correctly)